# Ping6 no response time?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, ipv6

I'm trying to ping6 an address. If there's a response it's fine. If there's no response, the ping takes anywhere between 100-300ms to return. Is there a way to set the no response time? What's the default no response time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no response, ping6 will time out, i.e. it will wait for a response for a duration t and then report "destination unreachable".

To change the default duration, use the -W option: -W timeout

http://man.he.net/man8/ping6

Comment: Thanks for your response. -W timeout is in seconds. I need something in the tunes of milliseconds.

Comment: Get the sources for ping6 and add such an option yourself ? :)